# Copying row to a different tab when deleting it data

Tags: excel, vba

When deleting a product from the "Prod_List"(sheet2) I need to copy the row and paste it into a "DeletedList"(sheet3).
This sub "Delete_product" should, from the display on the "Summary"(sheet1) ask the user to confirm the action, then copy the row from the "Prod_List"(sheet2), pasting it into the "DeletedList"(sheet3) and clean the view from the display on the "Summary"(sheet1)

```
'Delete Product
Option Explicit
Dim PRodRow As Long, ProdCol As Long

Sub Delete_Product()
With Summary
If .Range("B8").Value = Empty Then
MsgBox "Please Select a correct product to delete"
Exit Sub
End If

If MsgBox("Are you sure you want to delete this Product?", vbYesNo, "Delete Product") = vbNo Then Exit Sub

 PRodRow = DeletedList.Range("A999999").End(xlUp).Row + 1
 For ProdCol = 1 To 22
 'DeletedList.Cells(PRodRow, ProdCol).Value = .Range(DeletedList.Cells(1, ProdCol).Value).Value 'add data to product to deleted tab

Next
With Prod_List
PRodRow = Summary.Range("B8").Value 'product row
Prod_List.Range(PRodRow & ":" & PRodRow).EntireRow.Delete

 
   With Summary

.Range("J4,J5,J6,J7,J9,J10,n5,J11,N7,N8,N9,N12,N13,N14,J13,J14,J15").ClearContents

End With
End With
End With
End Sub
```

When I run it, it deletes the row correctly, however, it doesn't copy the row into the "DeletedList"(sheet3), however, when the line below is not as an observation the data is pasted on the "DeletedList"(sheet3), but it doesn't delete it from the "ProductList"(sheet2)

- 'DeletedList.Cells(PRodRow, ProdCol).Value =
  .Range(DeletedList.Cells(1, ProdCol).Value).Value 'add data to
  product to deleted tab "

Any ideas or suggestions on how to fix it?

Thank you!

Comment: `Prod_List.Range(PRodRow & ":" & PRodRow)` This needs to be something like A1:A2. I think you just have numbers now.

Comment: DeletedList is not declared or set anywhere (assuming it's a worksheet variable). Same goes for `Summary`. Is this pseudo code? How is this not erroring out since you have option explicit

Comment: thanks for the message,I'm a really beginner in VBA, and I'm still not familiar with everything

@findwindow do i need to add the specific row? i thought when using `Summary.Range("B8"). Value`, excel would be able to update to the correct row, ("B8") is updated every time with the relevant row number i want to have the change made before i run this sub (copy-past-delete)

Comment: @urdearboy, i tried adding `Dim ws As DeletedList` at the beginning of the code, but it didn't work, i also tried using `with DeletedList` before the line that gives me the error didn't work. How should i declare it correctly?

Comment: `Dim ws As Worksheet` and then `Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("DeletedList")`

Comment: Then you can refer to that worksheet with the variable `ws`. So something like `ws.Range("A1").Copy`